# Kotlin Json parsing MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, gson, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to learn MVVM architecture on parse Json into a Recyclerview in MVVM using coroutines. But I'm getting error on BlogRepository class.

My Json file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "potter",
    "img": "https://images.example.com/potter.jpg"
},
{ …}
]
```

I have created data class as below:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class ABCCharacters (

    @Json(name = "id") val char_id: Int,
    @Json(name = "name") val name: String? = null,
    @Json(name = "img") val img: String
)
```

Then the RestApiService as below:

```
interface RestApiService {

    @GET("/api")
    fun getPopularBlog(): Deferred<List<ABCCharacters>>

    companion object {

        fun createCorService(): RestApiService {

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com")
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .build().create(RestApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

BlogReposity.kt

```
class BlogRepository() {

    private var character = mutableListOf<ABCCharacters>()
    private var mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<ABCCharacters>>()
    val completableJob = Job()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + completableJob)

    private val thisApiCorService by lazy {
        RestApiService.createCorService()
    }

    fun getMutableLiveData():MutableLiveData<List<ABCCharacters>> {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val request = thisApiCorService.getPopularBlog()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                try {

                    val response = request.await()
                    val mBlogWrapper = response;
                    if (mBlogWrapper != null && mBlogWrapper.name != null) {
                        character = mBlogWrapper.name as MutableList<ABCCharacters>
                        mutableLiveData.value=character;
                    }

                } catch (e: HttpException) {
                    // Log exception //

                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    // Log error //)
                }
            }
        }
        return mutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

Finally the ViewModel class

```
class MainViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    val characterRepository= BlogRepository()
    val allBlog: LiveData<List<ABCCharacters>> get() = characterRepository.getMutableLiveData()

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        characterRepository.completableJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

I've done this based on https://itnext.io/kotlin-wrapping-your-head-around-livedata-mutablelivedata-coroutine-networking-and-viewmodel-b552c3a74eec 
Someone can guide me where am I going wrong & how to fix it?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm getting error "Unresolved reference" on this line (.name): if (mBlogWrapper != null && mBlogWrapper.name != null) {
                        character = mBlogWrapper.name as MutableList<ABCCharacters>
                        mutableLiveData.value=character;
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getPopularBlog()` API return `List<ABCCharacters>` instead of `ABCCharacters`. So, you can't access `ABCCharacters`'s property from your response directly. That's why `name` property here shows `Unresolved reference`.

Try below code:

```
if (mBlogWrapper != null && mBlogWrapper.isNotEmpty()) {
    character = mBlogWrapper as MutableList<ABCCharacters>
    mutableLiveData.value = character
}
```

Comment: Hey @GK007, Did you check the answer?

Comment: Thanks. The error is gone now but getting blank screen with no errors. What could be the issue?

Comment: Debug your code and check whether `mBlogWrapper ` is empty or not. I have checked with example data from your linked source and found everything ok. If you share your api then i can check

Comment: Your sample `json` in this post and API `json` is not same. Then how it works with your above code?

Comment: Also I need your Activity/Fragment code where you initialize RecyclerView with adapter

Comment: But that is different problem. I think your mentioned problem is solved already. If you debug then you can find it. In that case accept the answer and post another with details and give me the link. It will help this post to remain clean. And It's recommended by **SO** to ask separate question in separate thread. Hope you understand.

Comment: Sure.. check this link please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58825330/blank-screen-with-recyclerview-no-adapter-attached

Comment: @GK007, Check my answer there and let me know. And why not you give upvote? It help others to find it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your response return List but you want to check single object value (mBlogWrapper.name != null). You dont need this line on your code. In the example he checked if "response" is not a "null" and if the blog list is not null. Analize example one more time ;)

if you still have a problem with it, let me know